# How to get the max of an arbitrary function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2, enumerator

Consider some function `foo`:

```
def foo(input)
  input * 2
end
```

How to get the max value of input for some array `a`?

```
a = [3, 5, 7, 9, 6]
```

Something like the following (which doesn't work) should return 9:

```
a.max do |value|
  foo(value)
end
```

How to do it?

Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `max_by` , not `max`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by

`max`:

> Returns the object in enum with the maximum value. The first form
>   assumes all objects implement Comparable; the second uses the block to
>   return a <=> b.

```
a = %w(albatross dog horse)
a.max                                  #=> "horse"
a.max {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length }   #=> "albatross"
```

So `max` does take a block, but it doesn't do what you expected it to.

`max_by`:

> Returns the object in enum that gives the maximum value from the given
>   block.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
a = %w(albatross dog horse)
a.max_by {|x| x.length }   #=> "albatross"
```

Comment: @BSeven Accept this answer if you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

use array map: `a.map{|v|foo(v)}.max`

Comment: This returns the max of foo(v), which is 18.

Comment: right, didn't get the question correctly, if you need to find exact element not result, the above answer is good: a.max_by{|v|foo(v)}